# How to use regex to find all overlapping matches

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find every 10 digit series of numbers within a larger series of numbers using re in Python 2.6.

I'm easily able to grab no overlapping matches, but I want every match in the number series.  Eg.

in "123456789123456789"

I should get the following list:

```
[1234567891,2345678912,3456789123,4567891234,5678912345,6789123456,7891234567,8912345678,9123456789]
```

I've found references to a "lookahead", but the examples I've seen only show pairs of numbers rather than larger groupings and I haven't been able to convert them beyond the two digits.

Comment: The presented solutions won't work when the overlapping matches start at the same point, e.g., matching "a|ab|abc" against "abcd" will only return one result. Is there a solution for that that does not involve calling match() multiple times, manually keeping track of the 'end' boundary?

Comment: @VítorDeAraújo: overlapping regexes like `(a|ab|abc)` can generally be rewritten as non-overlapping ones with nested capture-groups, e.g. `(a(b(c)?)?)?`, where we ignore all but the outermost (i.e. leftmost) capture group when unpacking a match; admittedly this is slightly painful and less legible. This will also be a more performant regex to match.

Answer (score 273, accepted):

Use a capturing group inside a lookahead. The lookahead captures the text you're interested in, but the actual match is technically the zero-width substring before the lookahead, so the matches are technically non-overlapping:

```
import re 
s = "123456789123456789"
matches = re.finditer(r'(?=(\d{10}))', s)
results = [int(match.group(1)) for match in matches]
# results: 
# [1234567891,
#  2345678912,
#  3456789123,
#  4567891234,
#  5678912345,
#  6789123456,
#  7891234567,
#  8912345678,
#  9123456789]
```

Comment: My answer is at least 2 times faster than this one. But this solution is tricky, I upvote it.

Comment: Explanation = instead of searching for the pattern (10 digits), it searches for anything FOLLOWED BY the pattern. So it finds position 0 of the string, position 1 of the string and so on. Then it grabs group(1) - the matching pattern and makes a list of those. VERY cool.

Comment: I had no idea you could use matching groups inside lookaheads, which normally aren't supposed to be included in a match (and the matched subgroups indeed do not appear the full match). As this technique still seems to work in Python 3.4, I guess it's considered a feature rather than a bug.

Comment: I joined StackOverflow, answered questions, and got my reputation up just so I could upvote this answer. I'm stuck with Python 2.4 for now so I can't use the more advanced regex functions of Python 3, and this is just the sort of bizarre trickery I was looking for.

Comment: Could you add more explanation to the code. Its not the best way as per Stack Overflow, to just have code in an answer. It will definitely help people.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to convert the matches to integers?  Is it to generate the non-string output desired in the question?  I need the same system, but not with integers.  (In fact, I will be pulling the index of the match, not the data)

Comment: Just in case anyone only extracts strings, `re.findall(r'(?=(\d{10}))', s)` will do.

Answer (score 108):

You can also try using the [third-party `regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) (not `re`), which supports overlapping matches.

```
>>> import regex as re
>>> s = "123456789123456789"
>>> matches = re.findall(r'\d{10}', s, overlapped=True)
>>> for match in matches: print(match)  # print match
...
1234567891
2345678912
3456789123
4567891234
5678912345
6789123456
7891234567
8912345678
9123456789
```

Answer (score 14):

I'm fond of regexes, but they are not needed here.

Simply

```
s =  "123456789123456789"

n = 10
li = [ s[i:i+n] for i in xrange(len(s)-n+1) ]
print '\n'.join(li)
```

result

```
1234567891
2345678912
3456789123
4567891234
5678912345
6789123456
7891234567
8912345678
9123456789
```

Comment: Regexes are only not needed here because you're applying the special knowledge "within a larger series of numbers", so you already know every position `0 <= i < len(s)-n+1` is guaranteed to be the start of a 10-digit match. Also I figure your code could be sped up, would be interesting to code-golf for speed.

Answer (score 5):

Piggybacking on the accepted answer, the following currently works as well

```
import re
s = "123456789123456789"
matches = re.findall(r'(?=(\d{10}))',s)
results = [int(match) for match in matches]
```