# Get all possible matches for regex (in python)?

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I have a regex that can match a string in multiple overlapping possible ways. However, it seems to only capture one possible match in the string, how can I get all possible matches? I've tried finditer with no success, but maybe I'm using it wrong.

The string I'm trying to parse is:

```
foo-foobar-foobaz
```

The regex I'm using is:

```
(.*)-(.*)

>>> s = "foo-foobar-foobaz"
>>> matches = re.finditer(r'(.*)-(.*)', s)
>>> [match.group(1) for match in matches]
['foo-foobar']
```

I want the match (foo and foobar-foobaz), but it seems to only get (foo-foobar and foobaz).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches

Comment: @Ray Toal Thanks! I actually viewed that one earlier and upvoted it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No problem:

```
>>> regex = "([^-]*-)(?=([^-]*))"
>>> for result in re.finditer(regex, "foo-foobar-foobaz"):
>>>     print("".join(result.groups()))
foo-foobar
foobar-foobaz
```

By putting the second capturing parenthesis in a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), you can capture its contents without consuming it in the overall match.

I've also used `[^-]*` instead of `.*` because the dot also matches the separator `-` which you probably don't want.

Answer (score 2):

It's not something regex engines tend to be able to do. I don't know if Python can. Perl can using the following:

```
local our @matches;
"foo-foobar-foobaz" =~ /
    ^(.*)-(.*)\z
    (?{ push @matches, [ $1, $2 ] })
    (*FAIL)
/xs;
```

This specific problem can probably be solved using the regex engine in many languages using the following technique:

```
my @matches;
while ("foo-foobar-foobaz" =~ /(?=-(.*)\z)/gsp) {
   push @matches, [ ${^PREMATCH}, $1 ];
}
```

(`${^PREMATCH}` refers to what comes before where the regex matched, and `$1` refers to what the first `()` matched.)

But you can easily solve this specific problem outside the regex engine:

```
my @parts = split(/-/, "foo-foobar-foobaz");
my @matches;
for (1..$#parts) {
   push @matches, [
      join('-', @parts[0..$_-1]),
      join('-', @parts[$_..$#parts]),
   ];
}
```

Sorry for using Perl syntax, but should be able to get the idea. Translations to Python welcome.

Comment: @user449511, Added another method that should be easy to implement in Python.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect overlapping matches, you'll have to implement it yourself - essentially, for a string `foo`

1. Find the first match that starts at string index `i`
2. Run the matching function again against `foo[i+1:]`
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 on the incrementally short remaining portion of the string.

It gets trickier if you're using arbitrary-length capture groups (e.g. `(.*)`) because you probably don't want both `foo-foobar` and `oo-foobar` as matches, so you'd have to do some extra analysis to move `i` even farther than just `+1` each match; you'd need to move it the entire length of the first captured group's value, plus one.

Comment: Not really. You can capture overlapping matches easily using lookahead assertions.

Comment: Oh, quite true. Hadn't occurred to me mostly because I was in the "not changing the original pattern" mindset, and thus just suggesting programmatic solutions. +1 for your answer here. :)