# Python regex extract IPs separated with colon

Tags: python, regex

Here is an example: '192.168.1.1;192.168.1.2'

My code:

```
import re
regex = '^((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)[;]?)+$'
r = re.match(regex, '192.168.1.1;192.168.1.2')
r.groups() # => ('192.168.1.2',)
# My expected result => ('192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2',)

# re.findall(regex, '192.168.1.1;192.168.1.2') => ['192.168.1.2'] is not what I want......
```

I use `()` to capture each IP, but the result only shows one IP.
Is my usage wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: [How can I find all matches to a regular expression in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697882/how-can-i-find-all-matches-to-a-regular-expression-in-python) and [Python - Using regex to find multiple matches and print them out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724993/python-using-regex-to-find-multiple-matches-and-print-them-out) and [Get all possible matches for regex (in python)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383818/get-all-possible-matches-for-regex-in-python)

Comment: Use [`findall`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall)

Comment: do u want both IPs on different lines?

Comment: @Tushar `findall` doesn't show the two IPs in a list. I think maybe my regex is wrong...

Comment: @stribizhev I think the issue is with the regex, `findall` will not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `re.finditer()`

```
import re
regex = '^((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)[;]?)+$'
for r in re.finditer(regex, '192.168.1.1;192.168.1.2'):
  print r.group()
```

You can use this regex also if u want:
`regex = r'(\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d\.\d)'`

Comment: This only shows `192.168.11.1;192.168.12.1`, but I want to extract the two ip to a list.

Comment: use the regex provided by me and then append it to a list.

Comment: Oh..., you mean `regex = r'(\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d\.\d)'` ? I think this format is not what I want.