# Python re not finding all groups

Tags: python, regex, string

I got `word = abccabcc` and i need to find all repeating groups as follows:

```
regex = (.+)(.+)\1\2
```

so basically `word = uv` where u can be: `u = abc` and v can be: `v = c` but using python `re` lib `findall()` returns only above pair but not all possible pairs such as `u = ab` `v = cc`.

I also tried overlapped feature in regex lib but with no success.

```
regex = r"(.+)(.+)\1\2"
chunkRegex = re.compile(regex)
sub = chunkRegex.findall(word)
print(sub) # [('abc', 'c')]
```

Exapected output for given example should be and possible there are more valid matches:

```
[('abc', 'c'), ('ab', 'cc'), ('a', 'bcc')]
```

Example in online regex matcher: https://regex101.com/r/1IZUpp/1

Comment: I tried something similar to what you sugesst but it returnes abccabcc. I think there may be something wrong dou to overlapping but i don't know how to fix it

Comment: I would reopen my question cuz its not duplicated

Comment: You should edit your question and include your exact expected output for this case, that would help make the question clear.

Comment: I said it can be. And later in post i said it not retuning all possible values of u and v. Only the first example.

I expact my program ot return list of all possible overlapping groups. For my example it should be:

(abcc c)
(ab, cc)

etc...

Comment: Please clean up the comments. I think the problem should not be solved with a regex. It does not work the way you expect it to.

Comment: Your question title is wrong: 're.findall()` doesn't claim to match all possible combinations of all the possible pattersn that match your regex: it matches the first pattern it can. So your question should be more like 'how do I find all possible matches to a regex'?  That may be a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383818/get-all-possible-matches-for-regex-in-python - don't think it can be solved just witrh regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i know how to solve this without regex but i need to use re lib unfortunately.

Comment: @barny yes you are correct i should have rephrase title cuz findall returnes all non overlapping matches

Comment: Then you are stuck forever. Regexps do not work this way, back and forth throughout the string.

Comment: @JvdV i tried but suprisingly it returnes same as standard re