# Python: how the get the consecutive n-size pieces in a string?

Tags: python

Given a string such as `"8584320342564023450211233923239923239110001012346596"`, how can get all consecutive 4 digit subsequences?

For example, the above string will produce: `8548`, `5843`, `8432`,  `0342`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex solution:

```
import re
re.findall("[0-9]{4}","8584320342564023450211233923239923239110001012346596")
```

**EDIT**: Thanks to the comment I see what you actually wanted was all overlapping matches. I found an existing stackoverflow answer to that here:
[Python regex find all overlapping matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches)

Using that as a hint to the regular expression needed. In your case you can use:

```
>>> re.findall("(?=(\d{4}))","8584320342564023450211233923239923239110001012346596")
['8584', '5843', '8432', '4320', '3203', '2034', '0342', '3425', '4256', '2564', '5640', '6402', '4023', '0234', '2345', '3450', '4502', '5021', '0211', '2112', '1123', '1233', '2339', '3392', '3923', '9232', '2323', '3239', '2399', '3992', '9923', '9232', '2323', '3239', '2391', '3911', '9110', '1100', '1000', '0001', '0010', '0101', '1012', '0123', '1234', '2346', '3465', '4659', '6596']
```

Comment: Your regular expression groups every set of 4, OP's question wants each group of 4 with each character in the string. Your code would do something like "8584", "3202"..., whereas the question wanted "8584", "5843"...

Answer (score 6):

I think this does what you want:

```
es = '8584320342564023450211233923239923239110001012346596'
strings = [es[x:x+4] for x in xrange(0, len(es)-3)]
```

Output

```
>> strings
Out[42]: 
['8584',
 '5843',
 '8432',
 '4320',
 '3203',
 '2034',
 '0342',
 '3425',
 '4256',
 '2564',
 '5640',
 '6402',
 '4023',
 '0234',
 '2345',
 '3450',
 '4502',
 '5021',
 '0211',
 '2112',
 '1123',
 '1233',

  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get a subsequence of `n` characters starting from `i`<sup>th</sup> position using this code :

```
str[i:i+n]
```

Be careful that 0<sup>th</sup> position is starting of the string not 1<sup>st</sup>. I mean `str[0:0+n]` will give you the first n characters not `str[1:1+n]`

Here is the code:

```
s =  "8584320342564023450211233923239923239110001012346596"

for i in range(len(s) - 3):
    print(s[i:i+4])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data = "8584320342564023450211233923239923239110001012346596"
span = 4
for i in range(len(data) - span + 1):
    print data[i:i+span]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> line = "8584320342564023450211233923239923239110001012346596"
>>> map(''.join, zip(*(islice(line,i,None) for i in range(4))))
['8584', '5843', '8432', '4320', '3203', '2034', '0342', '3425', '4256', '2564', '5640', '6402', '4023', '0234', '2345', '3450', '4502', '5021', '0211', '2112', '1123', '1233', '2339', '3392', '3923', '9232', '2323', '3239', '2399', '3992', '9923', '9232', '2323', '3239', '2391', '3911', '9110', '1100', '1000', '0001', '0010', '0101', '1012', '0123', '1234', '2346', '3465', '4659', '6596']
```

Answer (score 0):

This will set output to contain a list of lists with a leaf for each 4 character sequence:

```
output = []
for i in range(len(input) - 3):
    output.append(input[i:i+4])
```