# Why doesn't python's re.findall return all the found substrings in my example?

Tags: python, findall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python regex find all overlapping matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches)

I don't see why python's re.findall does not return all the found substrings in my example below. Any ideas?

```
>>> import re
import re
>>> t='1 2 3'
t='1 2 3'
>>> m=re.findall('\d\s\d',t)
m=re.findall('\d\s\d',t)
>>> m
m
['1 2']
```

But the expected result is 
m = ['1 2', '2 3'].

For info, I am using python 2.6.1. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`help(re.findall)`

> Help on function findall in module re:
>
> findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
>   Return a list of all
>   non-overlapping matches in the string.
>
> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a
>   list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than
>   one group.
>
> Empty matches are included in the result.

Since the two results overlap (both have the '2' in them) only the first one will be returned.

if instead you will have `t='1 2 3 4'` the result will be `['1 2', '3 4']`.

Comment: Thanks. What would be the solution if the overlapped matches are desired?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches