# Python regex: overlapping patterns

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a string:

```
string = 'AvBvC'
```

I want to match `A`, `B`, and `C`, and this is what I did:

```
match = re.search('(.*)v(.*)', string)
print match.groups()
```

The problem is, the result shows that:

```
('AvB', 'C',)
```

instead of what I want, which is

```
('A', 'B', 'C',)
```

How do I make it catch all overlapping patterns..?

Thanks.

(I know there are some posts concerning the same issue, but haven't found a definite answer for Python)

Comment: Please spell out the *exact* output you want.  Can't guess.

Comment: @Tim Peters sorry I want ('A', 'B', 'C',)

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Yeah!! just modified my post (my original code is way longer and more complicated than this,, sorry)

Comment: More details would help - you can do what the above question asks with just `split('v')`, so I can only assume you have a more complicated situation.

Comment: This may be what you are after?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449800/python-regex-nested-parenthesis

Comment: If I remember my computing theory correctly, standard regular expressions can't parse nested parens. Some languages have recursion extensions to their regexps but python does not.

Comment: By default, regular expressions are greedy, so they will try to match as much as possible. Hence, `.*v.*`, which matches any run of characters, will match `('AvB', 'C')`. Please read the entirety of http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 2):

Your question is somewhat **unclear**, you seem to have more of a complicated string than you actual show.

Using `search()` matches only the first occurrence, you can use `findall()` to match all occurrences.

```
matches = re.findall(r'[^v]+', string)
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Another option would be to `split` on certain characters that you need to split on.

```
>>> re.split('v', 'AvBvC')
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Comment: This works for my example, but my actual string contains things that are not single character such as A,B,C... So is there a way to do this while using "search" instead of "findall"??

Comment: `search()` and `match()` return exactly 1 result.  So, no.  You need to make your question clearer ;-)

Comment: @TimPeters Why negative lookahead doesnt allow me to match beginning of the string?

Comment: @thefourtheye, huh? Without some context (or code), I don't know what you're asking - sorry.

Comment: @TimPeters `print re.findall("(?<=v|^).*?(?=v|$)", myString)` I tired this and it throws `sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`

Comment: @hwnd http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449800/python-regex-nested-parenthesis

Comment: @thefourtheye, that's look-behind, not look-ahead ;-) The error msg explained it: all alternatives in a lookbehind must match the same number of characters.  `v` matches 1 character but `^` matches 0 characters.  That's all there is to it.

Comment: @TimPeters Some people refer to that as negative look-ahead ;) If that is the case, why look-ahead accepts `$`?

Comment: @thefourtheye, then some people are bound to get confused by sloppy terminology ;-)  The "fixed width" restriction is unique to look-behinds - it does not apply to look-aheads.  The reason is simply the sheer difficulty of implementing varying-width look-behinds; they're "highly unnatural" for a "left to right" search engine.

Comment: @TimPeters Cool :) Thanks :) BTW, you mind [joining us](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) sometime

Answer (score 2):

Use `re.split`

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split('v', 'AvBvC')
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

And to demonstrate further...

```
>>> re.split('vw', 'AAvwBBvwCC')
['AA', 'BB', 'CC']
```