# regex of overlapping patterns

Tags: python, regex, overlapping

I am trying to match all instances of the pattern in the string using Python. However, when the patterns overlap I get only the longest one, while I need both:

```
import re
st = '''GYMGMTPRLGLESLLEStopAS'''
w = re.findall("M\w*?(?=Stop)",st)
print w
```

Output:

```
1. MGMTPRLGLESLLE
```

Desired output:

```
1. MGMTPRLGLESLLE
2. MTPRLGLESLLE
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python regex find all overlapping matches?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches)

Comment: This is probably a significant variant of that one.

Answer (score 4):

`(?=(M\w*?)Stop)`  Then the overlapp data is in capture group 1.