# How to find the total number of occurrences of the characters of a word in a string?

Tags: python, regex, string, substring

I'm new to Python, and I would like to find a substring in a string.

For example, if I have a substring of some constant letters such as:

```
substring = 'sdkj'
```

And a  string of some letters such as:

```
string = 'sdjskjhdvsnea'
```

I want to make a counter so that any letters `S`, `D`, `K`, and `J` found in the string the counter will get incremented by 1. For example, for the above example, the counter will be `8`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please update your question so it's clear what you really want, because am your question and the accepted answer don't match

Comment: @TimCastelijns the second part of the accepted answe works perfectly for the question as for the first part its for finding a whole substring in a substring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May this code can help you:

```
>>> string = 'sdjskjhdvsnea'
>>> substring = 'sdkj'
>>> counter = 0
>>> for x in string:
...     if x in substring:
...         counter += 1


>>> counter
8
>>>
```

Comment: Just to clarify! The "if x in substring:" is inside the "for x in string:"-loop. Kind of hard to see.

Comment: Yes right, if x ... is inside for x in string: loop.

Comment: @hakar,  just want to know if this is a right answer, if so feel free to mark it as a correct answer, otherwise, i can improve the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: oh, thank you alot, it really worked, but what if we want to find the whole substring in the string for example if the string is string = 'sdkjhsgshfsdkj' so the counter is equal to 2 in this case??

Comment: @Hakar that is a totally different question, and (per my answer) what is usually meant by *"finding a substring"*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so how to do that one, can you tell me please? i mean the second question

Comment: @Hakar at the risk of self-promotion, why not read my answer?

Comment: @TokSoegiharto note that this approach is `O(len(string)*len(substring))`, so will not be efficient if those strings get larger.

Comment: @jonrsharpe excuse me? which comment bro? did you comment the code for finding an entire substring in  a string? i haven't seen it

Comment: @TokSoegiharto no problem - it's unlikely to matter in this trivial case, but something to be aware of.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I just want to make a help.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**:

As you apparently *do* want the count of the appearances of the whole four-character `substring`, regex is probably the easiest method:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = 'sdkjhsgshfsdkj'
>>> substring = 'sdkj'
>>> len(re.findall(substring, string))
2
```

[`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) will give you a list of all (non-overlapping) appearances of `substring` in `string`:

```
>>> re.findall('sdkj', 'sdkjhsgshfsdkj')
['sdkj', 'sdkj']
```

---

Normally, *"finding a sub-string `'sdkj'`"* would mean trying to locate the appearances of that *complete four-character `substring`* within the larger `string`. In this case, it appears that you simply want the sum of the counts of those four letters:

```
sum(string.count(c) for c in substring)
```

Or, more efficiently, use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(string)
sum(counts.get(c, 0) for c in substring)
```

This only iterates over `string` once, rather than once for each `c in substring`, so is `O(m+n)` rather than `O(m*n)` (where `m == len(string)` and `n == len(substring)`).

In action:

```
>>> string = "sdjskjhdvsnea"
>>> substring = "sdkj"
>>> sum(string.count(c) for c in substring)
8
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter(string)
>>> sum(counts.get(c, 0) for c in substring)
8
```

Note that you may want [`set(substring)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-set) to avoid double-counting:

```
>>> sum(string.count(c) for c in "sdjks")
11
>>> sum(string.count(c) for c in set("sdjks"))
8
```

Comment: import re
>>> string = 'sdkjhsgshfsdkj'
>>> substring = 'sdkj'
>>> len(re.findall(substring, string))
2
this one is great, but how to save the value in a variable "counter" in this case??

Comment: @Hakar uh... `counter = len(...)`?!

Comment: yes I fixed that in anotherway, but there is a problem:
what is the substring starts and ends with the same letter, lemme explain it in an example
substring = 'sdks'
string = 'sdksjhgsdksdks'

Comment: @Hakar Per the documentation I have already linked to, `re.findall` is **non-overlapping**. If you have overlapping substrings, consider a [moving window approach](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6822725/3001761) or use [`re.match`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5616822/3001761).

Comment: i think my case is not overlapping as i looked at the links u gave, what i want if the the last letter of the substring is same as the last letter and in the string we have a concatination of of the substring but with the same letter in common, for example:
substring = 'sdks' string = 'sdksjhgsdksdkshjhsdks'  so the counter will be three in this case as there is two sdks and an sdksdks which will be treated as two not one because the S in the middle will be the last letter of the first one and the first letter of the second one

Comment: @Hakar you realised that what you just described is overlapping, right? Also, it's "concatenation".

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution using [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> import re
>>> substring = 'sdkj'
>>> string = 'sdjskjhdvsnea'
>>> len(re.findall('|'.join(list(substring)), string))
8
```

Comment: Did you really mean to include `// 8`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Erm, that was meant to be a comment. I should have used `#` instead. Anyway, updated! :)