# Find shortest matches between two strings

Tags: python, regex

I have a large log file, and I want to extract a multi-line string between two strings: `start` and `end`.

The following is sample from the `inputfile`:

```
start spam
start rubbish
start wait for it...
    profit!
here end
start garbage
start second match
win. end
```

The desired solution should print:

```
start wait for it...
    profit!
here end
start second match
win. end
```

I tried a simple regex but it returned everything from `start spam`. How should this be done?

**Edit: Additional info on real-life computational complexity**:

- actual file size: 2GB
- occurrences of 'start': ~ 12 M, evenly distributed
- occurences of 'end': ~800, near the end of the file.

Comment: Well, if you want to match between `start` and `end`, then it's normal that you get `start spam` as the beginning result... Could you clarify the behavior that you want?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This regex should match what you want:

```
(start((?!start).)*?end)
```

Use `re.findall` method and single-line modifier `re.S` to get all the occurences in a multi-line string:

```
re.findall('(start((?!start).)*?end)', text, re.S)
```

See a test [here](http://regex101.com/r/iR6nR4/1).

Comment: Good answer and demo on regex101. The key that I was missing was the negative lookahead. Really useful.

Comment: Working in JS as well.

Comment: Could you explain `((?!start).)`?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi See [Tempered Greedy Token - What is different about placing the dot before the negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970).

Comment: In case you start having performance issues using this pattern use `re.findall(r'(start([^se]*(?:s(?!tart)[^se]*|e(?!nd)[^se]*)*end)', text)`

Comment: but why doesn't `start.*?end` work?

Answer (score 1):

Do it with code - basic state machine:

```
open = False
tmp = []
for ln in fi:
    if 'start' in ln:
        if open:
            tmp = []
        else:
            open = True

    if open:
        tmp.append(ln)

    if 'end' in ln:
        open = False
        for x in tmp:
            print x
        tmp = []
```

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky to do because by default, the `re` module does not look at overlapping matches. Newer versions of Python have a new `regex` module that allows for overlapping matches.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

You'd want to use something like

```
regex.findall(pattern, string, overlapped=True)
```

If you're stuck with Python 2.x or something else that doesn't have `regex`, it's still possible with some trickery. One brilliant person solved it here:

[Python regex find all overlapping matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches)

Once you have all possible overlapping (non-greedy, I imagine) matches, just determine which one is shortest, which should be easy.

Comment: I added some information on the actual size of the log file. In this case, storing all overlapping matches would exceed the disk space of my computer.

Comment: Well, the solution I linked to returns an iterator, so you wouldn't actually need to store all overlapping matches, just one or two at a time. But given the format of the file you're trying to parse, the accepted solution is probably better for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You could do `(?s)start.*?(?=end|start)(?:end)?`, then filter out everything not ending in "end".