# less command search

Tags: regex

I have a server that I cannot access the log files directly. For security reasons, access to the logs is via a script that executes the less command.

The contents of the log file are similar to:

```
08:03:52,143 DEBUG sessionid1111111 [za.co.phuthib.Service1] (http-/0.0.0.0:8905-4) initialiseProperties(): currentDate: 20160812
08:03:52,143 DEBUG sessionid1111111 [za.co.phuthib.Service1] (http-/0.0.0.0:8905-4) cached object found
08:03:52,143 INFO  sessionid1111111 [za.co.phuthib.Service2] (http-/0.0.0.0:8905-4) passphrase: 243989895859385938394583945839548983423488234
08:03:52,143 INFO  sessionid1111111 [za.co.phuthib.Service2] (http-/0.0.0.0:8905-4) chanellID: [CHANNELID]
08:03:52,144 INFO  sessionid1111111 [za.co.phuthib.Service3] (http-/0.0.0.0:8905-4) POST: /za/co/phuthib/retrieveProductList/
08:03:52,144 INFO  sessionid1111111 [za.co.phuthib.Service3] (http-/0.0.0.0:8905-4) Input: {"id":"3989349"}
08:03:52,812 INFO  sessionid1111111 [za.co.phuthib.Service3] (http-/0.0.0.0:8905-4) Response code [200 OK])
```

The server accepts many requests from many users and as such one needs to search through the file to find the information they need.

I am able to search for **sessionid1111111** and am also able to search for **za.co.phuthib.Service3** independantly.

I am trying to search for **za.co.phuthib.Service3** and **sessionid1111111**. 
I tried it with regular expressions but cannot seem to get it working, for example:

```
/sessionid1111111[\s]Service3
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `/\vsessionid1+ +\[za\.co\.phuthib\.Service3\]`?

Comment: Or `:g/sessionid1111111//Service3` ?

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew Thank you I can get the results I want with this approach. dNitro, your solution is more elegant and I would prefer that as its easier to remember but I cannot get it working

Comment: Did you notice that its a **command** and not a **regex**?!!! It simply selects all lines that includes *sessionid1111111* and search for *Service3* by this lines through `/Service3`.

Comment: Mind that *elegant* does not always mean *precise*. However, if you search for literals, you really should be using a command like dNitro's one, and it is working.

Comment: I think I'm missing something. When I do :g in the less command gives me a prompt

Comment: Try `/sessionid1111111.*Service3`. `[\s]` matches just a single whitespace character.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, that works perfectly and easy to remember as well

Comment: @Phuthib: But with `.*` you will match *any* line that contains sessionid1111111` and `Service3` even if the `Service3` is not part of the `phuthib` value in the square brackets. Can you afford your pattern to be that imprecise?

Comment: My objective is to identify Service3 calls made by sessionid1111111. This works well for the case. I was also able to run it with /sessionid1111111.*za\.co\.phuthib\.Service3 to add some precission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex pattern that is *precise* (will match only the Service3 in the `[...]` with `phuthib` inside:

```
sessionid1111111 +\[za\.co\.phuthib\.Service3]
```

Note that here,  `+` matches 1 or more spaces, `\[` matches a literal `[` and a `\.` matches a literal `.`.

If you do not need that level of precision, just use

```
sessionid1111111.*Service3
```

or a shorter

```
sessionid1{7}.*Service3
```

Where `.*` matches 0+ chars, as many as possible, and `1{7}` matches seven consecutive `1` chars.

Note that `sessionid1{7}.*Service3` will also find a  match in `sessionid111111111122234567 [za.co.phuthib.Service1]  (http-/0.0.0.0:8905-4) Input: {"name":"Service3"}`, that is why I strongly recommend making your pattern as  *precise* as can be.

Comment: With more experience now, I now usually use the none greedy version: sessionid1111111.*?Service3   The ? character will return the first occurring Service3 after sessionid1111111

Comment: @Phuthib Congratulations. Lazy and greedy quantifiers are actually [a very well known topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions). Common dupes for the questions sounding "why does my pattern match to the last occurrence..." are [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444/) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503413). Now, time to learn [tempered greedy token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24640154/). More info on [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794).