# get last occurrence of first pattern

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am trying to fetch the last occurrence of the patterns where the string contains similar patterns in between. 
E.g: my string is : "abc abc abc efg 123 abc 123 abc abc xyz 123"
I want to capture the pattern between abc and 123. 
My desired output is:
 ['abc efg 123', 'abc 123', 'abc xyz 123']

So I used regex 'abc.*?123'. But this is giving as follows:
 ['abc abc abc efg 123', 'abc 123', 'abc abc xyz 123']

I don't want first occurrence of first pattern to second pattern, I need last occurrence of first pattern to second pattern

```
import re
a="abc abc abc efg 123 abc 123 abc abc xyz 123"
print a
b=re.findall(r'abc.*?123',a)
print "Output is: "+str(b)
```

Output is:  ['abc abc abc efg 123', 'abc 123', 'abc abc xyz 123']

I expect the output as:  ['abc efg 123', 'abc 123', 'abc xyz 123']

Comment: What do you  expect for `abc efg abc 123` Perhaps like this https://regex101.com/r/PXU3dG/1

Comment: Do you mean that you want to capture non-repeating patterns? You can easily split on spaces and remove repeated entries in Python.

Comment: **Duplicate of [Find shortest matches between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24640154/find-shortest-matches-between-two-strings)**

Comment: The duplicate refers to using a Tempered Greedy Token which will not allow to match abc efg abc 123.

Comment: The TGT is exactly what OP asks for in the question: *I need **last occurrence** of first pattern to second pattern*. If the input is `abc efg abc 123`, the output must be `abc 123`. Please re-close.

Comment: The question starts with `fetch last occurrence of the patterns where the string contains similar patterns in between.` Due to the `the similar patterns in between` part I asked the OP if `abc efg abc 123` can be a match and the reply in the comment listed under the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57495751/5424988) is `Yes, 'abc efg abc 123' can also be a match.` The TGT will not match that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the last occurrence of abc in `abc abc abc`, you could use a negative lookahead `(?! abc)` to assert abc is not followed by a space and abc. Use word boundaries `\b` to prevent abc being part of a larger word.

If there can be a single occurrence of `abc` after `efg` you might use:

```
\babc\b(?! abc\b).*?\b123\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3jKy6Z/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/C9o6pI)

```
import re
a="abc abc abc efg 123 abc 123 abc abc xyz 123"
b=re.findall(r"\babc\b(?! abc\b).*?\b123\b",a)
print (b)
```

Result

> ['abc efg 123', 'abc 123', 'abc xyz 123']

Comment: Albeit impressive, it relies on hardcoded patterns. I am going to assume OP is looking for a generic solution which can be used on any string.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus The example data as well as the pattern contains `abc` and `123`. A more generic pattern could be `\b(\w+)\b(?! \1).*?123` https://regex101.com/r/x3qXal/1 or with `\S+` instead of `\w+`

Comment: Thank you. This is working. My actual case is even little more complicated where I need to capture multiple patterns in single regex. Let me try more and come back. Once again thanks a lot for this as this will resolve many of my issues. Great..!!!!

Comment: @mangipudiphanikishore Can this also be a match? `abc efg abc 123`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes, 'abc efg abc 123' can also be a match. Thinking how can we make an expression if there are more than 2 patterns. E.g pattern1 might be abc, pattern2 might be 'efg' and pattern3 might be '123'. Can we write in one regexp?

Comment: @Phani Do you mean like this using capturing group and a backreference https://regex101.com/r/MpzAiJ/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes, the above is even more close to my solution. I just updated like this : (abc(?! abc).*?efg)(?! abc|efg).*?123                                                             Because 'abc' followed by 'efg' followed by '123' followed by so on...

Comment: @Phani Ok, I will remove the duplicate marking as it refers to using a [Tempered Greedy Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat/37343088#37343088) which will not allow to [match](https://regex101.com/r/okiJSK/1) `abc efg abc 123`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Got it. Thank you for the solutions. Working perfect