# Replace only last occurrence of regex

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have an XML code and I want to replace something in it.
If there is `"\\d{4}s</w:t>"` I want to replace the LAST occurrence of `"<w:rPr>"` before this with `"<w:rPr><w:keepNext/>"` and I don't know how. 
What I tried is `"str_replace_all(Text, "(<w:rPr>.*?)(\\d{4}s</w:t>)", "\\1<w:keepNext/>\\2")"` but this does not replace the last occurrence of `"<w:rPr>"`.

I asked a similar question before but it was closed because it was too similiar to [Find shortest matches between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24640154/find-shortest-matches-between-two-strings).
But this did not help me.

EDIT:
Here is a similar example:
`str_replace_all("hallohallohallo text bye hallohallo text2 bye", "(hallo)(.*?bye)", "\\1,\\2")` leads to `"hallo,hallohallo text bye hallo,hallo text2 bye"` and I want `"hallohallohallo, text bye hallohallo, text2 bye"`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely follow the XML matching (I'm not that well versed in parsing/selecting XML), but to the similar example, use the `+` character to create a group of one or more.

````r
myText <- "hallohallohallo text bye hallohallo text2 bye"

str_replace_all(myText, "((hallo)+)(.*?bye)", "\\1,\\3")
#> [1] "hallohallohallo, text bye hallohallo, text2 bye"
```
````

Comment: Thank you for your help! As I see now, this similar example is not what I was really looking for. I have another solution that I'm not 100% satisfied with but it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that I've found:

```
str_split(Text, "(?<=<w:pPr>)") %>%
  unlist %>% 
  modify_if(~ str_detect(.x, "\\d{4}s</w:t>"), ~ str_c("<w:keepNext/>", .x)) %>% 
  str_c(collapse = "")
```