# re.finditer() returning same value for start and end methods

Tags: python, regex, python-itertools

I'm having some trouble with the re.finditer() method in python. For example:

```
>>>sequence = 'atgaggagccccaagcttactcgatttaacgcccgcagcctcgccaaaccaccaaacacacca'
>>>[[m.start(),m.end()] for m in re.finditer(r'(?=gatttaacg)',sequence)]

out: [[22,22]]
```

As you can see, the `start()` and `end()` methods are giving the same value. I've noticed this before and just ended up using `m.start()+len(query_sequence)`, instead of `m.end()`, but I am very confused why this is happening.

Comment: Why are you using a lookahead?

Comment: I'm using the lookahead because I want overlapping matches. For example if I was searching for aca, I'd want acaca to count as 2 occurrences instead of 1

Comment: Well, you know the length of the requested sequence, so why do you even need `m.end()`?

Comment: Ok then removing the lookahead is not going to work, just adding the length to start is your only option

Comment: The lookahead isn't part of the match. The match starts and ends at position 22, even though the fact that it's a match depends on characters after that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module supports overlapping with finditer :

```
import regex
sequence = 'acaca'
print [[m.start(), m.end()] for m in regex.finditer(r'(aca)', sequence, overlapped=1)]
[0, 3], [2, 5]]
```

Comment: Beautiful answer. This makes sense.

Comment: @lstbl: Note that the `regex` module in this answer is an entirely different module from the standard-library `re` module you're using.

Comment: I did not notice that

Comment: @lstbl you need to install `regex` module through `pip` or something and you are good to go

Answer (score 2):

```
sequence = 'atgaggagccccaagcttactcgatttaacgcccgcagcctcgccaaaccaccaaacacacca'
print [[m.start(),m.end()] for m in re.finditer(r'(gatttaacg)',sequence)]
```

remove the `lookahead` .It does not capture only asserts.

Output:`[[22, 31]]`

if you have to use `lookahead` use

```
sequence = 'atgaggagccccaagcttactcgatttaacgcccgcagcctcgccaaaccaccaaacacacca'
print [[m.start(),m.start()+len("aca")] for m in re.finditer(r'(?=aca)',sequence)]
```

Comment: A clarification: this means that when `re.finditer` matches `gatttaacg`, the actual values aren't consumed. It only goes to that position and says "yes, what is ahead of this position is the string requested".

Comment: so the end() function is essentially worthless if you are using a lookahead?

Comment: @lstbl `lookaheads` dont consume any string.They just check a string after a position.So you get the start but regex engine remains there as no string is consumed thereafter

Answer (score 1):

As specified, you are required to find overlapping matches and need the lookahead. However, you appear to know the exact string you're looking for. How about this?

```
def find_overlapping(sequence, matchstr):
    for m in re.finditer('(?={})'.format(matchstr)):
        yield (m.start(), m.start() + len(matchstr))
```

Alternatively, you could use the third-party Python [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18966891/1530134).

Comment: This works. It was what I was using originally. I'm still a bit confused why the regex engine can't successfully determine how long the match is (for example if the length of the regex match was not known apriori, like it is in my case), since it is still able to determine if there is a match.

Comment: @lstbl, it can. `m.start()` and `m.end()` refer to the spans of group 0, which is empty. So you are just misinterpreting the API.

Answer (score 1):

If the length of the subsequence is not known a-priori, then you can use a matching group inside the lookahead and take its [span](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.span):

```
[m.span(1) for m in re.finditer(r'(?=(gatttaacg))',sequence)] == [(22,31)]
```

E.g. to find all repeated characters:

```
[m.span(1) for m in re.finditer(r'(?=(([acgt])\2+))',sequence)]
```