# regular expression for title case - Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I need to find a combination of 2 consecutive title case words.

This is my code so far,

```
text='Hi my name is Moh Shai and This Is a Python Code with Regex and Needs Some Expertise'

rex=r'[A-Z][a-z]+\s+[A-Z][a-z]+'

re.findall(rex,text)
```

This gives me,

```
['Moh Shai', 'This Is', 'Python Code', 'Needs Some']
```

However, I need all the combinations. Something like,

```
['Moh Shai', 'This Is', 'Python Code', 'Needs Some','Some Expertise']
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches) help?

Comment: If you can install a third-party module, the easiest way is with the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), which supports an `overlapped=True` flag on `findall()`.

Comment: @kindall you are awesome. That works great! Can you please post an answer so I may accept?

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regex lookahead in combination with the `re.finditer` function in order to get the desired outcome:

```
import re

text='Hi my name is Moh Shai and This Is a Python Code with Regex and Needs Some Expertise'
rex=r'(?=([A-Z][a-z]+\s+[A-Z][a-z]+))'

matches = re.finditer(rex,text)
results = [match.group(1) for match in matches]
```

Now results will contain the information you need:

```
>>> results
['Moh Shai', 'This Is', 'Python Code', 'Needs Some', 'Some Expertise']
```

---

edit: For what it's worth, you don't even really need the `finditer` function. You can replace those bottom two lines with your previous line `re.findall(rex,text)` for the same effect.

Comment: This answer identifies only Title Case of 2 words, it would fail on "The United States Of America"

Comment: Yes, as requested in the question.

Answer (score 3):

I came to this question by It's title and was disappointed that the solution wasn't what I expected.

The accepted answer only works for titles of **exactly** 2 words

This code would return all of the tokens that are in title case, without assuming anything on the amount of words in the title

```
import re, collections
def title_case_to_token(c):
    totoken = lambda s: s[0] + "<" + s[1:-2].replace(" ","_") + ">" + s[-2:]
    tokenized = re.sub("([\s\.\,;]([A-Z][a-z]+[\s\.\,;])+[^A-Z])", lambda m: totoken(m.group(0))," " + c + " x")[1:-2]
    tokens = collections.Counter(re.compile("<\w+>").findall(tokenized))
    return (tokens, tokenized)
```

For example

```
text='Hi my name is Moh Shai and This Is a Python Code with Regex and Needs Some Expertise'
tokens, tokenized = title_case_to_token(text)
```

Value of `tokens`

```
Counter({'<Hi>': 1, '<Moh_Shai>': 1, '<This_Is>': 1, '<Python_Code>': 1, '<Regex>': 1, '<Needs_Some_Expertise>': 1})
```

### Note that `Needs_Some_Expertise` is also caught by this regex, and it has 3 words

Value of `tokenized`

```
<Hi> my name is <Moh_Shai> and <This_Is> a <Python_Code> with <Regex> and <Needs_Some_Expertise>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can install a third-party module, the easiest way is with the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), which supports an `overlapped=True` flag on `findall()`.