# Regex: counting the amount of times substring occurs in string including overlapping occurrences

Tags: python, regex, string, overlapping

I'm doing a problem on rosalind that wants you to return the positions that a substring occurs in a longer string. The only problem is there is an overlapping occurrence and the output should be: 1, 3, 9 (assuming 0 based counting) but I'm only getting 1 and 9? Here's my code.

```
import re

s='GATATATGCATATACTT'
t='ATAT'

substrings=re.compile('ATAT')
matches=substrings.finditer(s)

for match in matches:
     print(match.start()+1)  #doesn't find overlapping ones
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can install a third-party module, the `regex` module has an extended version of the `re` module API that allows an `overlapped=True` argument to be passed to `findall` and `finditer`.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

Otherwise, you might be able to adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36731305/416467).

Comment: One upvote for the `regex` module.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use lookahead.

```
import re
s='GATATATGCATATACTT'
t='ATAT'
print([match.start() for match in re.finditer('(?=%s)' % t, s)])
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 9]
```

Comment: Could you actually explain what a lookahead is? I'm a python beginner (a programming beginner actually) and haven't ever heard the phrase? How does it work?

Comment: I think this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups and this http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html.

Answer (score 1):

A 10 second search revealed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches).

You basically have to surround your RegEx with "(?=" and ")". This is a positive lookahead, resulting in the RegEx that doesn't block parts of the string for future matches.

**Be sure to capture group 1.**

I hope I could help,

CodenameLambda