# Find all overlapping patterns infinite loop, using Python 3 and dynamic programming

Tags: python, regex, search, position, findall

I was looking at: 
[Python regex find all overlapping matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches) and the `re.finditer` didn't work for me.  I don't want to download yet another module (i.e. `regex`) to replace the built-in `re`.  I thought I could write my own but my understanding of `while loops` is limited.

I'm trying to make a search wrapper that finds all patterns even if they are overlapping (one thing the current `findall` does not do in `re`).

I've also never tried to program something like this so instead of using a built-in module for this, I would like to try and construct my own function so I can learn how to program dynamically.

```
def findall_positions(pattern, sequence):
    positions = list()
    cont = True

    while cont == True:
        match = re.search(pattern, sequence)
        if match is not None:
            positions.append(match.start())
            sequence = sequence[positions[-1]:]
        if match is None:
            cont = False
    return positions

findall_positions("AB","ABBABBABBBA")
```

My logic was to do `re.search` and if there is a hit, append the start to `positions`, then get next stretch of the string after that first `re.search match` and iterate through this until `match is None`.  However, I'm getting an infinite loop.  **How can I restructure this to get the correct results?** I'm looking for an output of `[0,3,6]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with above approach is that the start of first match is at offset `0` and thus on the first iteration `positions` is `[0]`. Then `sequence = sequence[positions[-1]:]` naturally results to original string and thus you have infinite loop.

You could have a separate variable to keep track of the offset and construct new string every time you do `re.search`. If match is found then adjust the position accordingly:

```
import re

def findall_positions(pattern, sequence):
    positions = list()
    cont = True
    offset = 0

    while cont == True:
        match = re.search(pattern, sequence[offset:])
        if match is not None:
            positions.append(match.start() + offset)
            offset = positions[-1] + 1
        if match is None:
            cont = False
    return positions

print(findall_positions("AB","ABBABBABBBA"))
```

Output:

```
[0, 3, 6]
```