# Regex/Python missed encompassed pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have tried to research answers to this question online, but nothing seems to describe the problem I have here. If I missed something, please close the question and redirect it to where it has already been answered.

That being said, my python regex doesn't seem to want to recognize a pattern if it is already encompassed in another captured pattern. I tried to run the code and here are the results:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = 'NNTSY'
>>> m = re.findall('N[^P][ST][^P]',string)
>>> m
['NNTS']
```

I don't understand why it didn't yield this output:

```
>>> m
    ['NNTS','NTSY']
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### `re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)`
>
> Return all **non-overlapping** matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall

If you're not just trying to understand why, but actually need to get overlapping matches, you can use lookahead with a capturing group as described [in this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I ended up using the answer in the redirected question and it worked beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

This is in fact possible, using a lookahead assertion.

```
(?=pattern)
```

will match at any position directly followed by pattern without consuming the string, and

```
(?=(pattern))
```

will capture the group that matched.

```
import re
string = 'NNTSY'
m = re.findall(r'(?=(N[^P][ST][^P]))',string)
print(m)
#['NNTS', 'NTSY']
```