# Extracting all strings of length 2 with Re.Findall

Tags: python, regex

I would like to extract all 2-letter strings from a text with a regular expression, for example :

```
just a test
```

would get me `ju, us, st, te, es, st`

I tried using : `re.findall(r'\w{2}',text)` but it only divides the words into 2-letter strings and gives me `ju, st, te, st`

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: Use [`re.findall(r'(?=(\w{2}))',text)`](http://ideone.com/XucVPm).

Comment: without regex: `print(["".join(x)  for w in "just a test".split() if len(w)>1 for x in zip(w,w[1:])])`

Comment: @sin: he marked as duplicate then commented (not answered) to help the OP in his specific question. I just wished I could post my non-regex solution.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Life is hard and then you die.

Comment: @BillBell actually I could have reopened the question by myself, but I tend to avoid that by respect of other python gold badge holders. I guess Wiktor did that, so now I posted my answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew since it's not a dupe anymore why don't you answer? you commented first with a valid snippet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python regex find all overlapping matches?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Some of us deserve no respect. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'll leave the regex solutions to regex experts (which I'm not), since it can be done without regex quite simply in a one-liner list comprehension:

```
s = "just a test"
result = ["".join(x)  for w in s.split() if len(w)>1 for x in zip(w,w[1:])]

print(result)
```

result:

```
['ju', 'us', 'st', 'te', 'es', 'st']
```

Just split the words, filtering out words with less than 2 characters, and interleave them against their shifted copy using `zip`

only works if there's no punctuation of course.