# How to make my regexp searchs for ALL possible matches?

Tags: python, regex, string

My question is how can i make my regular expression to use a part of a string to find a new match even if this string is already choosed as a match, i don't know how to clarify it more than that, consider this example:
I have a string which is

`1+2-3*4/5`

and i want to match every digit which is surrounded by two operator, my regular expression would be:

```
(([+]|[-]|[*]|[/])(\d)([+]|[-]|[*]|[/]))
```

which gives 2 matches, while i see 3 ('+2-','-3*' and '*4/'), this is because my pattern theoretically deletes a part of my string (the previous matche(s)) and use the rest of my string in the next searching. How do i enforce it to find ALL possible matches?

[Demo](http://regexr.com/3glje)

Any solution for my question/example would be very appreciated.

Comment: If matching only the numbers is sufficient, you could use `(?<=[+*/-])\d(?=[+*/-])`, using lookarounds. If you also want to match the operators, you might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches

Comment: I think you want to use positive lookaheads, read up on those.

Comment: Yes, lookarounds/aheads solved my problem.