# Python regular expression findall using Lookahead

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to regular expressions and would like to understand how **findall()** and **lookahead** can be used to find all occurrences of a given pattern within a string. I am having problems with alternating characters. Here is an example of what I want:

```
s = 'ababa4abaab'
p = 'aba'
print([ s[i:i+len(p)] for i in range(len(s)) if s[i:i+len(p)]==p])
['aba', 'aba', 'aba']
```

Here is my attempt with findall():

```
import re
re.findall('aba', 'ababa4abaab')
['aba', 'aba']
```

It only returns 2 matches but I want all three. I read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#regex-howto) tutorial but did not quite understand. I tried

```
re.findall('(?=aba)', 'ababa4abaab')
['', '', '']
```

Can someone please tell me how to use this lookahead concept in this case and provide a brief explanation of how it works?

Comment: What is your question about ? findall(), lookahead or finding recurring patterns ?

Comment: So, you want overlapping patterns. Use `import regex as re; re.findall('aba', 'ababa4abaab', overlapped=True)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python regex find all overlapping matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches)

Comment: Key thing is capturing the stuff you lookahead for.

Comment: Your regex quite literally means, find every empty string which is followed by "aba".

Comment: Thank you all. I'm still trying to understand things but your comments were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to search either there is an 'ab' and 'a' right after,
You don't need to catch it as 'aba', you can use this look ahead:

```
ab(?=a)
```

which gives you 3 matches.

you can also capture it inside a group and then iterate each one of them and concatenate 'a' so you'll end with the desired text 'aba' for each match

```
 (ab(?=a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Official doc about **findall** says it

> "Return a list of all **non-overlapping** matches in the string."