# Regex lookahead with parentheses

Tags: python, regex

What exactly is `re.findall('(?=(b))','bbbb')` doing? It returns `['b', 'b', 'b', 'b']`, but I expected `['b', 'b', 'b']`, since it should only return a 'b' if it sees another 'b' ahead?

Thanks!

Edit: It seems that `re.findall('b(?=(b))','bbbb')` returns `['b', 'b', 'b']` like I would expect, but I am still confused as to what `re.findall('(?=(b))','bbbb')` does.

Edit 2: Got it! Thank you for the responses.

Comment: It start from first index of input string and runs until last index if you do `re.findall('(?=(bb))','bbbb')` and output `['bb', 'bb', 'bb']`

Comment: I've reopened this question because it's not asking [how to find overlapping matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches), and [Reference - What does this regex mean?](//stackoverflow.com/q/22937618) is a useless duplicate target that should never be used as a duplicate target, ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a *zero-length match* there, *and* you have a capturing group. When the regular expression for `re.findall` has a capturing group, the resulting list will be what's been captured in *those capturing groups* (if anything).

Four positions are matched by your regex: the start of the string, before the first `b`, before the second `b`, and before the third `b`. Here's a diagram, where `|` represents the position matched (spaces added for illustration):

```
 b b b b
|         captures the next b, passes

 b b b b
  |       captures the next b, passes

 b b b b
    |     captures the next b, passes

 b b b b
      |   captures the next b, passes

 b b b b
        | lookahead fails, match fails
```

If you didn't want a capturing group and only want to match the zero-length positions instead, use `(?:` instead of `(` for a non-capturing group:

```
(?=(?:b))
```

(though the resulting list will be composed of empty strings and won't be very useful)

Comment: No need for a non-capturing group. `(?:b)` could just be `b`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the capturing group is *inside* the lookahead.

To do what you want you have to capture the letter, then use a lookahead that doesn't capture:

```
re.findall('(b)(?=b)','bbbb')
```

result:

```
['b', 'b', 'b']
```

Answer (score 1):

A positive lookahead `(?=` asserts a position which is found 4 times because there are 4 positions where a b follows. In that assertion itself you capture a `(b)` in a capturing group which will be returned by [findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=findall#re.findall).

If you want to return three times a `b` and you are not referring to the group anymore, you could match `b` and add a lookahead that asserts what is on the right side is a `b`

`print(re.findall('b(?=b)','bbbb'))`

[Demo](http://rextester.com/GWLXN47008)