# Adding items to list when they already exist and when using for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

This is a pretty simple question about lists and for loop.

Assuming I have the following 2d-list:

```
[

['c', 'a', 't', 'c', 'a', 't']

['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 't, 'l']

['c', 'a', 't', 'w', 'x', 'y']

]
```

And I want to iterate over the list using for loops, each time checking if the word 'cat' is in the list.
 If it is, I want to add it to the list every time it appears.

So my result should be `['cat', 'cat', 'cat, 'cat']`

My function receives a word list and a given matrix (2d list containing lists of letters).
My code is:

```
def search_for_words(word_list, matrix):
    results = []
    for word in word_list:
        for line in matrix:
            line_string = ''.join(line)
                if word in line_string:
                    results.append(word)
    return results
```

And it will returns me just 'cat' if cat is in thr word list.

I know I probably just need another if statement but I can figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I gave a wrong example.

consider this:

```
matrix = [['a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e'], 
      ['a', 'g', 'o', 'd', 'o'],
      ['n', 'n', 'e', 'r', 't'],
      ['g', 'a', 'T', 'A', 'C'],
      ['m', 'i', 'c', 's', 'r'],
      ['P', 'o', 'P', 'o', 'P']]
```

word_list = ['apple', 'god', 'dog', 'CAT', 'PoP', 'poeT]

my function returns :

['apple', 'god', 'PoP']

When I expect it to return 'PoP' twice because it appears twice at the bottom list.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can't reproduce your problem, code produces the correct output, assuming you fix your indentation error.

Comment: For me, the returned list has 3 occurrences of `cat` (instead of 4) but that is a different problem.

Comment: I edited my question with the appropriate example. Sorry for the confusion. @ggorlen

Comment: the line `if word in line_string` checks for the `word` in `line_string` only once. you will need to find the index of the first match then again look for the next match starting from the `index of the last match + 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're not checking how many times that substring occurs in the string. You also need to account for [overlapping matches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5616910/1822698):

```
import re

def search_for_words(word_list, matrix):
    results = []
    for word in word_list:
        for line in matrix:
            line_string = ''.join(line)
            # find all overlapping matches of word in line_string
            matches = re.findall(r'(?=(' + word + '))', line_string)
            results.extend(matches)
    return results
```

If we run this on your second matrix:

```
m = [['a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e'], 
     ['a', 'g', 'o', 'd', 'o'],
     ['n', 'n', 'e', 'r', 't'],
     ['g', 'a', 'T', 'A', 'C'],
     ['m', 'i', 'c', 's', 'r'],
     ['P', 'o', 'P', 'o', 'P']]

word_list = ['apple', 'god', 'dog', 'CAT', 'PoP', 'poeT']

print(search_for_words(word_list, m))
```

we see the following output:

```
['apple', 'god', 'PoP', 'PoP']
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is pretty simple. Just build a string and check it each time. Lose the first letter of the string if the string is longer than the target word.

```
outer = [['c', 'a', 't', 'c', 'a', 't'],
         ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 't', 'l'],
         ['c', 'a', 't', 'w', 'x', 'y']]

for inner in outer:
  word = ""
  target = "cat"
  t_len = len(target)
  for letter in inner:
    word += letter
    if len(word) > t_len:
      word = word[1:]
    if word in target:
      print(target)
```

For the answer to your second question, you're probably best to just `"".join()` all of the strings and parse them with regex.