# Empty Regex response using finditer and lookahead

Tags: python, regex, string, regex-lookarounds

I'm having trouble understanding regex behaviour when using lookahead.

I have a given string in which I have two overlapping patterns (starting with `M` and ending with `p`). My expected output would be `MGMTPRLGLESLLEp` and `MTPRLGLESLLEp`. My python code below results in two **empty** strings which share a common start with the expected output.

Removal of the lookahead `(?=)` results in only ONE output string which is the larger one. Is there a way to modify my regex term to prevent empty strings so that I can get both results with one regex term?

```
import re

string = 'GYMGMTPRLGLESLLEpApMIRVA'

pattern = re.compile(r'(?=M(.*?)p)')
sequences = pattern.finditer(string)

for results in sequences:
    print(results.group())
    print(results.start())
    print(results.end())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [overlapping matches trick with a look-ahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches) makes use of the fact that the `(?=...)` pattern matches at an empty location, then pulls out the captured group nested inside the look-ahead.

You need to print out group 1, explicitly:

```
for results in sequences:
    print(results.group(1))
```

This produces:

```
GMTPRLGLESLLE
TPRLGLESLLE
```

You probably want to include the `M` and `p` characters in the capturing group:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?=(M.*?p))')
```

at which point your output becomes:

```
MGMTPRLGLESLLEp
MTPRLGLESLLEp
```

Comment: You are completely right! Output now looks as expected. Thank you very much!