# Efficiently generate a list of all possible substrings of a string

Tags: python, c++, c, string, list

I want to write a function that efficiently returns a list of all possible substrings of a string according to a minimum and maximum length of the substrings. (The strings contain uppercase letters only.)

For example, for a String `'THISISASTRING'`, for `min_length=3` and `max_length=4`, it should return:

```
['THI', 'THIS', 'HIS', 'HISI', 'ISI', 'ISIS', 'SIS', 'SISA', 'ISA',
 'ISAS', 'SAS', 'SAST', 'AST', 'ASTR', 'STR', 'STRI', 'TRI', 'TRIN',
 'RIN', 'RING', 'ING']
```

I'm looking for a solution that is much faster than my current one:

```
import cProfile

random_english_text = \
    'AHOUSEISABUILDINGTHATISMADEFORPEOPLETOLIVEINITISAPERMANENTBUILDINGTHATISMEANTTOSTAYSTANDINGITISNOTEASILYPACKEDU' \
    'PANDCARRIEDAWAYLIKEATENTORMOVEDLIKEACARAVANIFPEOPLELIVEINTHESAMEHOUSEFORMORETHANASHORTSTAYTHENTHEYCALLITTHEIRHO' \
    'MEBEINGWITHOUTAHOMEISCALLEDHOMELESSNESSHOUSESCOMEINMANYDIFFERENTSHAPESANDSIZESTHEYMAYBEASSMALLASJUSTONEROOMORTH' \
    'EYMAYHAVEHUNDREDSOFROOMSTHEYALSOAREMADEMANYDIFFERENTSHAPESANDMAYHAVEJUSTONELEVELORSEVERALDIFFERENTLEVELSAHOUSEI' \
    'SSOMETIMESJOINEDTOOTHERHOUSESATTHESIDESTOMAKEATERRACEORROWHOUSEACONNECTEDROWOFHOUSES'

def assemble_substrings(textstring, length_min, length_max):
    str_len = len(textstring)
    subStringList = []
    idx = 0
    while idx <= str_len - length_min:
        max_depth = min(length_max, str_len - idx)
        for i in list(range(length_min, max_depth + 1)):
            subString = textstring[idx:idx + i]
            subStringList.append(subString)
        idx += 1
    return subStringList


pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()

for i in range(0, 1000):
    list_of_substrings = assemble_substrings(textstring=random_english_text, length_min=4, length_max=10)

pr.disable()
pr.print_stats(sort='cumtime')
```

which yields me:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     1000    1.332    0.001    1.672    0.002 <input>:11(assemble_substrings)
  3654000    0.227    0.000    0.227    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
   525000    0.112    0.000    0.112    0.000 {built-in method builtins.min}
     1000    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Now, from the output of the profiler, I don't get much insight on how to speed this function up.

What is the best way to make this function as fast as possible?
Should I use a different data structure than a list?
Use Cython? Or write this code in an external C/C++ shared object?

Would be highly appreciative for inputs, also generally on how to efficiently deal with strings and operations similar to the one above on them in Python.

Comment: What do you want to use this for? There may be a better data structure than a list with all the options.

Comment: Also I think you have a bug with an edge case, when the loop is at the last length_min characters of the string it still adds the string for each of the allowed lengths. I think the end of the string will need to be treated as a special case.

Comment: for all the items in the resulting list (or other data structure), i want to be able to:
1. check for each of them, if they are contained in another list (or other data structure)
2. iterate over all elements and use them as keys to access a dictionary

Comment: Your problem reminds me part of other problem although I can't remember which exactly. Maybe [k-nucleotide](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/description/knucleotide.html#knucleotide)?

Comment: Why are you using `list(range(...))`?  Seems like the call to `list()` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 6):

Why not simply use a list-comprehension over 2 ranges and string slicing?

```
t = "SOMETEXT"

print(t)

minl = 3
maxl = 8

parts = [t[i:i+j] for i in range(len(t)-minl) for j in range(minl,maxl+1)]

print(parts)
```

Output:

```
['SOM', 'SOME', 'SOMET', 'SOMETE', 'SOMETEX', 'SOMETEXT', 'OME', 'OMET', 'OMETE', 'OMETEX', 
 'OMETEXT', 'OMETEXT', 'MET', 'METE', 'METEX', 'METEXT', 'METEXT', 'METEXT', 'ETE', 'ETEX', 
 'ETEXT', 'ETEXT', 'ETEXT', 'ETEXT', 'TEX', 'TEXT', 'TEXT', 'TEXT', 'TEXT', 'TEXT']
```

You can use a set to remove dupes if order is not important - else create a unique list for in-order storage:

```
nodupes = [] 
k = set() 
for l in parts:
    if l in k:
        pass
    else:
        nodupes.append(l)
        k.add(l)

print(nodupes)
```

Output:

```
['SOM', 'SOME', 'SOMET', 'SOMETE', 'SOMETEX', 'SOMETEXT', 'OME', 'OMET', 'OMETE', 'OMETEX', 
 'OMETEXT', 'MET', 'METE', 'METEX', 'METEXT', 'ETE', 'ETEX', 'ETEXT', 'TEX', 'TEXT']
```

---

**With timings:**

```
def doit(t,minl,maxl):
    parts = [t[i:i+j] for i in range(len(t)-minl) for j in range(minl,maxl+1)]
    return parts

pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()

for i in range(0, 1000):
    list_of_substrings = doit(random_english_text, 4, 10)

pr.disable()
pr.print_stats(sort='cumtime')
```

---

```
         3001 function calls in 0.597 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     1000    0.001    0.000    0.597    0.001 main.py:10(doit)
     1000    0.596    0.001    0.596    0.001 main.py:11(<listcomp>)
     1000    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Yours gives: `4181001 function calls in 1.614 seconds`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Needless to say, your answer is way more elegant than mine. :)

Regarding speed, your solution is about 3 times faster than mine, which is already good but it would still be great if it could be much, much faster :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how fast it would actually be (*read*: need further investigation), but for me it sounds like task for regular expressions (`re` module), I would do it following way:

```
import re
minlen = 3
maxlen = 4
s = 'THISISASTRING'
out = []
for i in range(minlen,maxlen+1):
    p = re.compile('(?=(.{'+str(i)+'}))',re.DOTALL)
    out = out+p.findall(s)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
['THI', 'HIS', 'ISI', 'SIS', 'ISA', 'SAS', 'AST', 'STR', 'TRI', 'RIN', 'ING', 'THIS', 'HISI', 'ISIS', 'SISA', 'ISAS', 'SAST', 'ASTR', 'STRI', 'TRIN', 'RING']
```

I used *bernie* answer from this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches) to get `findall` to work in overlapping fashion. I know that this particular *Zero Length Assertion* could harness variable length patterns however when I did `re.findall('(?=(.{3,4}))','THISISASTRING')` it produced  `['THIS', 'HISI', 'ISIS', 'SISA', 'ISAS', 'SAST', 'ASTR', 'STRI', 'TRIN', 'RING', 'ING']` which is not desired output. Thus I present mixed `for-re` solution, with each turn of loop for particular length of string. There I must admit, that I am not good enough at `re`, to make it work in single-pass manner (solely `re`, without `for`), however maybe some other user will be able to accomplish it?

Comment: Thx for your answer, just checked and your solution is about 3 times faster than mine. However, I was rather hoping for a more drastic speedup. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can map `’’.join()` to zipped strings:

```
def func(s, min_l, max_l):
    return [subl for i in range(min_l, max_l + 1)
                 for subl in map(''.join, zip(*[s[i:] for i in range(i)]))]
```

### Profile:

```
random_english_text = \
    'AHOUSEISABUILDINGTHATISMADEFORPEOPLETOLIVEINITISAPERMANENTBUILDINGTHATISMEANTTOSTAYSTANDINGITISNOTEASILYPACKEDU' \
    'PANDCARRIEDAWAYLIKEATENTORMOVEDLIKEACARAVANIFPEOPLELIVEINTHESAMEHOUSEFORMORETHANASHORTSTAYTHENTHEYCALLITTHEIRHO' \
    'MEBEINGWITHOUTAHOMEISCALLEDHOMELESSNESSHOUSESCOMEINMANYDIFFERENTSHAPESANDSIZESTHEYMAYBEASSMALLASJUSTONEROOMORTH' \
    'EYMAYHAVEHUNDREDSOFROOMSTHEYALSOAREMADEMANYDIFFERENTSHAPESANDMAYHAVEJUSTONELEVELORSEVERALDIFFERENTLEVELSAHOUSEI' \
    'SSOMETIMESJOINEDTOOTHERHOUSESATTHESIDESTOMAKEATERRACEORROWHOUSEACONNECTEDROWOFHOUSES'

pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()

for i in range(0, 1000):
    list_of_substrings = func(random_english_text, 4, 10)

pr.disable()
pr.print_stats(sort='cumtime')
```

#### Output:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
  1000    0.002    0.000    0.772    0.001 Untitled.py:3(func)
  7000    0.014    0.000    0.014    0.000 Untitled.py:4(<listcomp>)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```