# Find all the locations of `0000` from string by python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to find all the locations of `0000` from string.

```
text = "001111000000010100000"
for m in re.finditer(r"0{4}", text):
    print(m)
```

This sample code result is below.

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(6, 10), match='0000'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(16, 20), match='0000'>
```

I can see where `finditer` found `0000` by `span`.
But what I was expecting is different.

My expectation is below.

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(6, 10), match='0000'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(7, 11), match='0000'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(8, 12), match='0000'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(9, 13), match='0000'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(16, 20), match='0000'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(17, 21), match='0000'>
```

How can I achieve my expectation?
If there is other useful built in method or python package, please advise me.

Thanks!

This question looks like same as mine at a grance.
However my question's point is `location`, not a `string`.

[Python regex find all overlapping matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches)

After reading above question, I got a hint.
Here is my modified code.

```
text = "001111000000010100000"
for m in re.finditer(r"(?=(0{4}))", text):
    print(m)
    print(f"Indexes: {m.span(1)}")
    print(f"Matched string: {m.group(1)}")
```

And the result is here.

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(6, 6), match=''>
Indexes: (6, 10)
Matched string: 0000
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(7, 7), match=''>
Indexes: (7, 11)
Matched string: 0000
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(8, 8), match=''>
Indexes: (8, 12)
Matched string: 0000
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(9, 9), match=''>
Indexes: (9, 13)
Matched string: 0000
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(16, 16), match=''>
Indexes: (16, 20)
Matched string: 0000
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(17, 17), match=''>
Indexes: (17, 21)
Matched string: 0000
```

This is what I was expecting.
Thank you for telling me good past question in past.