# Why is my positive lookahead assertion consuming the string and not matching correctly?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to find all the occurances of a substring inside a string and print their start and end index using regular expression.

For example,
    string = 'bbbcbb'
    sub = 'bb'
I must get (0,1) (1,2) (4,5) as my output.

### My code:

```
import re
matches = list(re.finditer(r'bb(?=[a-zA-Z]|$)', 'bbbcbb'))
```

## The output:

```
[<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='bb'>, 
<_sre.SRE_Match object;span=(4, 6), match='bb'>]
```

---

I went through the documentation on https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html and to my understanding the lookahead assertion will work by

1. At postion 0, it will match 'bb' with "bb" followed by "b" .i.e. **bb**bcbb
2. At postion 1, it will match 'bb' with "bb" followed by "c" .i.e. b**bb**cbb
3. Then it will not match till postion 4 where it will match 'bb' with "bb" followed by $ .i.e. bbbc**bb**

---

Why is the lookahead assertion ignoring the b'bb'cbb at the (1,3) position? Or is my understanding of the lookahead assertion flawed?

Comment: Algorithm you've described can be done with `(?=bb)` regex. If you want it to capture `bb` use `(?=(bb))`. [Link](https://regex101.com/r/7dahEz/1)

Comment: `$` is a special character and means the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with your lookahead, and is caused by `re` not returning overlapping matches.
Here's a simpler example:

```py
import re

regex = re.compile("aa")
results = list(regex.finditer("aaaa"))
#  You expect to get (0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4)
print(results)
>>> [<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='aa'>,
     <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(2, 4), match='aa'>]
```

The correct way to do this is by using groups and a lookahead, as explained here: [Python regex find all overlapping matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches)

Comment: This will not return the index of the matched substrings. I need to find the indices of the matched substrings.

Comment: You can use `groups` to find the groups that were captured and add those to the start indices of the match.

Comment: I tried this out. But the groups function returns the substring itself. What I did was add the length of the string - 1 to the start index of the match.

Comment: You can add another group to find the actual string `regex = re.compile("(?=(aa))")` and then add `len(x.groups(1)[0]))` to the start index. This makes you code a bit less reliant on the thing you are trying to find.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `'bb(?=[a-zA-Z]|$)` will match 2 characters instead of 1 asserting that what is on the right is a character a-z or the end of the string.

Using [re.finditer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer), you might update your pattern to match a single `b` and put a single `b` in the positive lookahead:

```
import re
matches = list(re.finditer(r'b(?=b)', 'bbbcbb'))
for m in matches:
    print(m.span())
```

Result

```
(0, 1)
(1, 2)
(4, 5)
```