# Capture string between \n [string] \n

Tags: python, regex, newline

I'm trying to parse YouTube description's of songs to compile into a .csv

Currently I can isolate timecodes, though making an attempt on isolating the song and artist is proving trickier.

First, I catch the whitesapce

```
# catches whitespace
pattern = re.compile(r'\s+')
```

Second, the timecodes (to make the string simpler to deal with)

```
# catches timecodes
pattern1 = re.compile(r'[\d\.-]+:[\d.-]+:[\d\.-]+')
```

then I sub and remove.

I then try to capture all strings between \n, as this is how the tracklist is formatted

```
songBeforeDash = re.search(r'^([\\n][a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*[\\n]*)+$', description)
```

The format follows **\n[string]-[string]\n**

Using this [excellent visualiser](https://www.debuggex.com/?flavor=python) , I've been able to tweak it so it catches the first result, however any subsequent results don't match. 
Is this a case of stopping at the first result and not catching the others?

Here's a sample of what I'm trying to catch

```
\nmiddleschoolxAso-Cypress\nShopan-Woodnot\nchromonicci-Memories.\nYasper-MoveTogether\nFenickxDelayde-Longwayhome\nauv-Rockaway5pm\nsadtoi-Aires\nGMillsxKyleMcEvoy-Haze\nRuckP-CoffeeBreak\n
```

Comment: some of the example string does not begin and end with \n

Comment: My apologies! Work got in the way and I forgot to check back. The most appropriate answer was accepted. Thank you all for helping, I've made progress in my program from being able to parse what I needed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with split()

```
t = '\nmiddleschoolxAso-Cypress\nShopan-Woodnot\nchromonicci-Memories.\nYasper-MoveTogether\nFenickxDelayde-Longwayhome\nauv-Rockaway5pm\nsadtoi-Aires\nGMillsxKyleMcEvoy-Haze\nRuckP-CoffeeBreak\n'

liste = t.split('\n')
liste = liste[1:-1:]
print(liste)
```

Comment: `liste = t.strip().split('\n')`

Comment: yeah it's better

Comment: @Alexall I tried this suggestion I'm given a blank array. [ ]

Comment: Your variable 'description' is a string ?

Comment: @Alexall it is string, yeah. 
In fact when I try and print now, I get a blank line.
Going through the debugger, the values beforehand are printing as normal. When it gets to the suggested code, there's no data displayed.

Comment: I tried again by cutting a section of string out like in your code, and it works flawlessly! My variable's string data then is the issue

https://pastebin.com/aFUKFBLg

Answer (score 2):

re.search only returns the first match in the string.
What you want is to use [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) which returns all matches.

---

**EDIT** - Because your matches would overlap, I would suggest editing the regex to capture until the next newline. Right now they cannot overlap. Consider changing the regex to this:

```py
r'^([\\n][a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*)+$'
```

If what you want is for them to overlap (meaning you want to capture the newlines too), I suggest looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5616910/12092543) to see how to capture overlapping regex patterns.

Also, as suggested by @ChatterOne, using the str.split(seperator) method would work well here, assuming no other type of information is present.

```py
descriptor.split('\n')
```

Comment: In this case it will not work anyway, because of the "greedy" behaviour of the regexp. And even if using a "lazy" behaviour (`.*?`) it will still not work because it will not use the ending `\n` as the starting point for a new match, so it will match one, skip one, match one, and so on. The best approach here is to use `split` as suggested in the other answer

Comment: Agree, fixed comment, added credit where credit is due.

Comment: `re.findall(r'(?<=\n)[^\n]+', description)`.