# How to find all the Occurance in the string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string '10101', need to find out the occurrence of '101' from the string. There are 2 occurrences of '101' first occurrence is from index 0 to 3 and the second occurrence is from index 3 to 5. How do I get this done using python?

Comment: I think your example indexes are off.0-2 and 2-4 ?

Comment: nobody said anything about this being about `regex`... I like the pure python version ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5616910/4518341):

```
import re
s = "10101"
matches = re.finditer(r'(?=(101))', s)
results = [m[1] for m in matches]
print(results)  # -> ['101', '101']
```

See the linked answer for details about how this works.

If you're using Python 3.5 or earlier, replace `m[1]` with `m.group(1)`.