# Find substrings matching a pattern allowing overlaps

Tags: python, regex

So I have strings that form concatenated 1's and 0's with length 12. Here are some examples:

```
100010011100
001111110000
001010100011
```

I want to isolate sections of each which start with 1, following with any numbers of zeros, and then ends with 1.

So for the first string, I would want `['10001','1001']`

The second string, I would want nothing returned

The third list, I would want `['101','101','10001']`

I've tried using a combination of positive lookahead and positive lookbehind, but it isn't working. This is what I've come up with so far `[(?<=1)0][0(?=1)]`

Comment: Easy to do with regex or pyparsing.

Comment: @pault, I'm having a really hard time getting the regex to "go back" and account for parts of the string already included in a previous slice.

Comment: @raphael I will look into pyparsing

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, for example, the string '10101', I would want it to split into ['101','101']. The second '1' would be used twice to form the last character of the first string and the first character of the second string in the list. However, when I used re.search() and re.findall() it only gives me ['101']

Comment: You should probably tag this as "algorithm"

Comment: @crayfishcray Yah, I keep rethinking how I would solve the problem and post a comment before double checking the documentation. My answer below provides a rough sketch of how I would do what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python regex find all overlapping matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches). From the accepted answer, the following should work for you: `re.findall("(?=(10+1))", myString)`

Comment: @BowlOfRed: even if it isn't the most straight forward method, I like your approach. (in which only the problematic 1 is in the lookahead and added after to the match result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a non-regex approach, you can split the string on `1`. The matches you want are any elements in the resulting list with a `0` in it, excluding the first and last elements of the array.

Code:

```
myStrings = [
    "100010011100",
    "001111110000",
    "001010100011"
]

for s in myStrings:
    matches = ["1"+z+"1" for i, z in enumerate(s.split("1")[:-1]) if (i>0) and ("0" in z)]
    print(matches)
```

Output:

```
#['10001', '1001']
#[]
#['101', '101', '10001']
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest writing a simple regex: `r'10+1'`. Then use python logic to find each match using `re.search()`. After each match, start the next search at the position after the beginning of the match.

Comment: and where is the code to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Can't do it in one search with a regex.

```
def parse(s):
    pattern = re.compile(r'(10+1)')
    match = pattern.search(s)
    while match:
        yield match[0]
        match = pattern.search(s, match.end()-1)
```