# Finding a given substring in a string with Regular Expression in Python

Tags: python, regex

## I am trying to find all the occurrences of a substring in a string like below:

```
import re
S = 'aaadaa'
matches = re.finditer('(aa)', S)
if matches:
  #print(matches)
  for match in matches:
   print(match)
else:
    print("No match")
```

The current output is:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 2), match='aa'>
<re.Match object; span=(4, 6), match='aa'>
```

But I am expecting that it should give the values as:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 2), match='aa'>
<re.Match object; span=(1, 3), match='aa'>
<re.Match object; span=(4, 6), match='aa'>
```

Could someone please help me on this?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `find*` functions just aren’t designed to return overlapping matches. It does look like [this](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) alternative RegEx library supports the feature.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python regex find all overlapping matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches)

Comment: Check this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring

Comment: @furkanayd Ah nice, it’s a more popular question than the one I found.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all occurrences of a substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring)

Comment: @furkanayd, Thanks and that works good, but the start and end indexes are printing to be same. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @Mathan it is because of the search text length I assume, try with len 3 string and corresponding main string such as "aaaadaaa" with "aaa", it will result with start = end - 1.

Comment: @furkanayd It isn't because of the text's length, it's the fact that the pattern's outer level is a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches) I linked in the comments, here is the pattern you need:
`(?=(aa))`.

You’ll have to access the matched substring using `match_obj.groups(1)`, and the match indices using `match_obj.span(1)`.

Comment: Yes, that works great. But when I tried to print the starting and ending indexes of those matches, it doesn't work as expected. It gives both starting and ending indexes as same like below: (0, 0)
(1, 1)
(4, 4)

Comment: Thanks, it prints the ending index increased by 1 as below as it uses the string slice mechanism (0, 2) (1, 3) (4, 6). But I should get (0, 1) (1, 2) (4, 5).

Comment: @Mathan I’m not sure what you mean. That’s just the way the match object counts indices. They’re the same indices as the ones in your post.

Comment: @Mathan Did you figure it out in the end?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that once the `re` module matches a double `aa`, it will also *consume* both of the letters.  But, you want overlapping matches.  One trick you could use here would be to search for `a(?=a)`:

```
S = 'aaadaa'
matches = re.findall(r'a(?=a)', S)
matches = [s + "a" for s in matches]
print(matches)

['aa', 'aa', 'aa']
```

Note that we tag on the second `a` to the output list, since only the first letter is actually matched at each step.