# One character in multiple groups

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like:

```py
s = 'ababbabbba'
```

I'm trying to match all patterns matching any number of *b*'s between *a*'s. This is what I expect the patterns to be for `s` above:

```py
['aba', 'abba', 'abbba']
```

This is what I've tried:

```py
import re
re.findall('ab+a', s)
```

Which gives:

```py
['aba', 'abbba']
```

I think that happens because any single *a* can only be part of a single group. Whereas my requirement would make the middle *a*'s be part of two groups. Reading through the `re` documentation, I can't find any way to do this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5616822/1324033

Comment: Duplicate of [Python regex find all overlapping matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comment above, the solution is:

```py
re.findall('(?=(ab+a))', s)
```