# Numeric pattern search in regular expression using Python

Tags: python, regex

I have text as below-

```
my_text = "My telephone number is 408-555-1234"
```

on which i am searching the pattern

```
re.findall(r'\d{3}-\d{1,}',my_text)
```

My intention was to search for three digit numeric value followed by `-` and then another set of one or more than one digit numeric value.  Hence I was expecting the result to be - `['408-555','555-1234']`,

However the result i am getting os only `['408-555']` .

Could anyone suggest me what is wrong in my understaning here. And suggest a pattern that would serve my purpose

Comment: I think this is because you already matched 555 you cant match it again.

Comment: You could use overlapping matches using a positive lookahead `print(re.findall(r'(?=(\d{3}-\d{1,}))',my_text))`

Comment: For finding overlapping matches, see [Python regex find all overlapping matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5616822/674064).

Comment: @das-g - Yes, this helps. I was not aware of this and it really helps. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
re.findall(r'(?=(\d{3}-\d+))', my_text)
```

output:

```
['408-555', '555-1234']
```