# Using Regex to match graph intervals

Tags: python, regex, numpy, regex-group

Say I have an array of numbers: `arr=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`.

Regular Regex has its basic units/literals as characters. I am wondering if there is a way to have "objects" as the basic unit, for an object `[a,b]`.

Now I want to answer the question, *"does `arr` contain at least 2 intervals of length 3 that have positive gradients?"*. I was thinking that I could mimic Regex by replacing characters with `[a,b]` objects, where `a` is the size of the interval and `b` is the function to run on that interval (`gradient_pos`). the function would return `True` or `False` depending on whether or not the condition was met. For example, to answer the above question, you would query:

`[3,gradient_pos]{2,}`

You will see that the syntax follows all the regex rules, except that rather than looking at characters, we are looking at `[a,b]` objects that effectively evaluate to `True` or `False`. The idea is that regex would try and match 2 or more intervals of length 3 that satisfy `gradient_pos`. Does that make sense? I know this is very abstract, but if anyone could help me out with achieving something like this, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treat it like a regex problem. So your array would become:

```
import numpy as np
arr=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
arr = np.array(arr)
arr_as_str=''.join(map(str,np.sign(arr[1:]-arr[:-1])+1))
```

I got the gradients excluding the last element and shifted the `sign` function from (-1,+1) to (0,2). The reason for that is to avoid the minus signs in the string representation.

So now you can just apply regex matching as usual where:

- negative gradient: 0
- zero gradient: 1
- positive gradient: 2

Your "3 consecutive positive gradients" query would look like this:

```
matches=list(re.finditer('(?=(2{3}))',arr_as_str))
```

Since there are overlapping regex matches, you have to use lookaheads like in:
[Python regex find all overlapping matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches)

You can refer back to the original array using the starting indices plus you know how long the sequences are:

```
matches[1].start()
```

I suggested this approach because it seems like you're comfortable with regular expressions. However, if you're interested in exploring other approaches I would recommend looking at [morphological filtering](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci773s1c/lectures/ImageProcessing-html/topic4.htm), it would have been my first choice

Comment: Thanks! Preprocessing definitely does seem like the best option, but I feel like it would be impossible to generalize to other functions/window sizes. I'll also check out morph filtering, thanks again!