# Finding all possible 5-letters combinations in a word using Regex (Python)

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to Python and to Regex. Here is my current problem, for which I have not managed to find any straight answer online.
I have a string of 5 or more characters, for which I need to search for all the possible combinations of 5 characters.

I wonder if it's doable with regular expressions (instead of, say, creating a list of all possible 5-character combinations and then testing them in loop with my string).

For example, let's say my string is "stackoverflow", I need an expression that could give me a list containing all the possible combinations of 5 successive letters, such as: ['stack', 'tacko', ackov', ...]. (but not 'stcko' or 'wolfr' for example).

That's what I would try:

```
import re
word = "stackoverflow"
list = re.findall(r".....", word)
```

But printing this list would only give:

```
['stack', 'overfl']
```

Thus it seems that a position can only be matched once, a 5-character combination cannot concern a position that has already been matched.

Could anyone help me better understand how regex work in this situation, and if my demand is even possible directly using regular expressions?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that regular expressions can help you here. Just write a loop and use the slice notation.

Comment: That's not combinations but substrings.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5616910/12693728, try:
```print([match.group(1) for match in re.finditer(r'(?=(.{5}))', "stackoverflow")])```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the letters are always consecutive, this will work:

```
wd = "stackoverflow" 
lst = ["".join(wd[i:i+5]) for i in range(len(wd)-4)]
print(lst)
```

Output

```
['stack', 'tacko', 'ackov', 'ckove', 'kover', 'overf', 'verfl', 'erflo', 'rflow']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just use a simple loop with a sliding window of size 5

```
word = "stackoverflow"
result=[]
for i in range(len(word)-5):
    result.append(word[i:i+5])
print(result)
```

This is quite efficient as it runs on O(n) linear time

Answer (score 0):

Because as I can see in findall documentation string it returns **all non-overlapping** matches:

```
def findall(pattern, string, flags=0):
    """Return a list of all non-overlapping matches in the string.

    If one or more capturing groups are present in the pattern, return
    a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
    has more than one group.

    Empty matches are included in the result."""
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
```

Look at solutions without regex usage in your topic.