# regex match all existing possibilities

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex pattern like this :

```
(?:(?:(?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9])) *[ /.-] *(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9]) *[ /.-] *(?:19\d{2}|20\d{2}|1[6-9]|2[0-9]))
```

I want to match it with this text :

```
001-001 09/23/2019 heure :42
```

What I am getting matched is:

```
01 09/23
```

What I want to have as match :

```
01 09/23 AND 09/23/2019
```

My code is actually :

```
regex = re.compile(pattern)
matches = regex.findall(text)
```

Is there any option I should turn on ?
Thanks

Comment: You could look into [overlapping matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches)

Comment: Overlapping matches, yes, but what are the rules? It is not quite clear why the expected result is not, say, `'01 09/23', '1 09/23', '09/23/2019', '9/23/2019']`

Comment: Does https://ideone.com/nHFWQl work as intended? Note I made days and months require a leading zero and applied the overlapping matches trick.

Answer (score -1):

As @The fourth bird suggest I looked to [overlapping matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches), and it worked with:

```
import regex as re
matches = re.findall(pattern, text, overlapped=True)
```

Comment: We do not answer duplicates, these questions must be closed. Simply let us know via a comment it is just what you need, and we'll close.