# How to extract the text between the word using RegEx?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have text like:

```
"ababbabbba"
```

I want to extract the characters as a list between a. For the above text, I am expecting output like:

```
['aba', 'abba', 'abbba']
```

I have used:

```
re.split(r'a(.*?)a', data)[1:-1]
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python regex find all overlapping matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches)

Comment: Why not something like: ['a' + t + 'a' for t in data.split('a')][1:-1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to use findall instead of split this works.

```
import re

s = "ababbabbba"

print(re.findall(r'(?=(a[^a]+a))',s))
```

prints:

```
['aba', 'abba', 'abbba']
```