# Best way to count the number of occurrences of a substring?

Tags: python

```
C = 'Kabansososkabansosos'
```

I need the number of times the string `'sos'` occurs in `C`. I've already used the `C.count('sos')` method, but it did not help me.

Comment: Do overlaps count? I.e. do you expect the answer to your example to be 2 or 4?

Comment: Always include a minimal version of your code plus your actual and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def count_occurrences(expression,word): 
    L = len(word)
    counts = 0
    for i in range(L,len(expression)+1):
        if expression[i-L:i]==word:
            counts += 1
    return counts

count_occurrences('Kabansososkabansosos','sos')
>>> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

To be explicit, your problem is that you want to count *non-overlapping* occurrences of the sub-string, which is not what `str.count()` does.

First, let's use the powerful [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) (regular expression) module instead of `str.count()`:

```py
C = 'Kabansososkabansosos'
matches = re.findall(r'sos', C)
n = len(matches)
print(n)  # 2
```

At first sight this seems silly, as it 1) also does not work with over-lapping occurrences and 2) produce a (potential) large list of matches, all of which will just be the `str` `'sos'`.

However, using the clever trick of the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches), we can make `re.findall()` work with overlapping occurrences:

```py
C = 'Kabansososkabansosos'
matches = re.findall(r'(?=(sos))', C)
n = len(matches)
print(n)  # 4
```

If `C` is very large, we would like to avoid the potentially large temporary `list` `matches`. We can do this by instead using the [`re.finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) function, which returns a generator rather than the `list`:

```py
C = 'Kabansososkabansosos'
matches = re.finditer(r'(?=(sos))', C)
n = sum(1 for match in matches)
print(n)  # 4
```

where the `sum()` over `1`s simply produce the length of the iterator, i.e. the number of matches.