# How to find all possible uniform substrings of a string?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string like

```
aaabbbbcca
```

And I'd like to parse all possible uniform substrings from that. So my expected substrings for this string are

```
['a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'b', 'bb', 'bbb', 'bbbb', 'c', 'cc', 'a']
```

I tried the following

```
import re

print(re.findall(r"([a-z])(?=\1*)", "aaabbbbcca"))
# Output: ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a']
```

Is it possible trough regular expressions? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve what you need **without a regex** here:

```py
result = []
text = "aaabbbbcca"
prev = ''
for c in text:
  if c == prev:
    result.append(result[-1] + c)
  else:
    result.append(c)
    prev = c
 
print(result)
# => ['a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'b', 'bb', 'bbb', 'bbbb', 'c', 'cc', 'a']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/9Ws1da).

In short, you can iterate over the string and append new item to a `result` list when the new char is not equal to the previous char, otherwise, append a new item with the value equal to the previous item + the same char concatenated to the value.

**With regex**, the best you can do is

```py
import re
text = "aaabbbbcca"
print( [x.group(1) for x in re.finditer(r'(?=((.)\2*))', text)] )
# => ['aaa', 'aa', 'a', 'bbbb', 'bbb', 'bb', 'b', 'cc', 'c', 'a']
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/U7eU8Z). Here, `(?=((.)\2*))` matches any location inside the string that is immediately preceded with any one char (other than line break chars if you do not use `re.DOTALL` option) that is followed with zero or more occurrences of the same char (capturing the char(s) into Group 1).

Answer (score 7):

You can use a regex to find streaks of the same character, and then some Python on top to build the smaller streaks.

```
import re

s = 'aaabbbbcca'
matches = (m.group() for m in re.finditer(r'([a-z])\1*', s))
result = [m[:i] for m in matches for i in range(1, len(m) + 1)]
```

There's also an `itertools` solution.

```
from itertools import groupby                                               
s = 'aaabbbbcca'                                                            
matches = (''.join(g) for _, g in groupby(s))                               
result = [m[:i] for m in matches for i in range(1, len(m) + 1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using two `itertools` functions:

```
from itertools import groupby, accumulate

s = 'aaabbbbcca'

print([a for _, g in groupby(s) for a in accumulate(g)])
```

Or just with basics:

```
s = 'aaabbbbcca'

a = ''
print([a := a * (c in a) + c for c in s])
```

Output for both:

```
['a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'b', 'bb', 'bbb', 'bbbb', 'c', 'cc', 'a']
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this particular problem can be solved with a regex. The answer is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5616910/7947994) answer, where parts of numbers are extracted. The explanation is the same as in the other answer. Each match creates an empty group and a group within the lookahead. The lookahead captures sequences of `a`, `b` or `c` of at least length 1. Afterward, we simply create a list of strings that are in the second group.

```
import re 

s = "aaabbbbcca"
matches = re.finditer(r'(?=(a{1,}|b{1,}|c{1,}))',s)
results = [match.group(1) for match in matches]
print(results)
```

Output:

```
['aaa', 'aa', 'a', 'bbbb', 'bbb', 'bb', 'b', 'cc', 'c', 'a']
```

The values of the output are the same as requested, but not the exact same order.

Comment: that implies all the elements in the string are known in advance