# Regex sub-substring appear k times within a larger substring of length n

Tags: python, string

Suppose you have a string that consists of the concatenation of `n` string tokens each of length `d`. What is the regex pattern that would match this string if and only if `n==N+2` (where `N` is a fixed) and a particular token appears between `k` and `N` times in it.

### Problem

Suppose we have (tokens of length `d=4`):

`s = "SbbESbbESbbEStbEStbESbbEStbESttE"`.

We would like to match substrings where `SbtE` appears exactly 2, 3, or 4 times (`k=2`) between a delimiting `SbbE` token and a delimiting token that's not `SbtE`, the delimiting tokens themselves 4 tokens apart (`N=4`).

### Desired solution

Adding spaces inside `s` for readability `s ~ "SbbE SbbE SbbE StbE StbE SbbE StbE SttE"`. Here, we have a total of 8 tokens, but we are looking for substrings containing exactly 4 tokens, which in turn contain between 2 and 4 appearances of `SbtE`. So, the first match should be from token 1 to token 6, and the second match should be from token 3 to token 8.

Is this even possible using regular expressions?

Answer (score 1):

Although this is doable with regex, it would probably be simpler to just split the string into tokens and process them. For example:

```py
d, k, N = 4, 2, 4
s = "SbbESbbESbbEStbEStbESbbEStbESttE"
tokens = [s[i:i+d] for i in range(0, len(s), d)]
matches = []
for i in range(len(tokens)-N-2+1):
    if (tokens[i] == 'SbbE' and 
        tokens[i+1:i+N+1].count('StbE') >= k and 
        tokens[i+N+1] != 'StbE'):
        matches.append(''.join(tokens[i:i+N+2]))

print(matches)
```

Output:

```
['SbbESbbESbbEStbEStbESbbE', 'SbbEStbEStbESbbEStbESttE']
```

If you are committed to using regex, you can use the following regex to match your requirements (for the specific `d, k, N = 4, 2, 4` case):

```
SbbE(?=(?:.{4}){0,2}(?:StbE){2}|(?:.{4})?StbE.{4}StbE|StbE.{8}StbE).{16}(?!StbE).{4}
```

This looks for:

- `Sbbe` : the string `Sbbe`
- (?= : a positive lookahead assertion for 3 alternatives:
  `(?:.{4}){0,2}(?:StbE){2}` : `StbEStbE` preceded by 0, 4, or 8 characters; or
  `(?:.{4})?StbE.{4}StbE` : `StbE....StbE` preceded by 0 or 4 characters; or
  `StbE.{8}StbE` : `StbE........StbE`
- `)` : end of assertion
- `.{16}` : match 16 characters
- `(?!StbE)` : a negative lookahead that says the next token is *not* `StbE`
- `.{4}` : 4 characters

Note that since you want 2 to 4 tokens in a substring of 4 tokens, you only need to check that at least 2 are present (hence the 3 alternatives in the positive lookahead).

Now since you want to find overlapping matches, we wrap the entire regex in a positive lookahead (as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5616910/9473764)):

```
(?=(SbbE(?=(?:.{4}){0,2}(?:StbE){2}|(?:.{4})?StbE.{4}StbE|StbE.{8}StbE).{16}(?!StbE).{4}))
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jLHAQW/1)

In python:

```py
s = "SbbESbbESbbEStbEStbESbbEStbESttE"
re.findall(r'(?=(SbbE(?=(?:.{4}){0,2}(?:StbE){2}|(?:.{4})?StbE.{4}StbE|StbE.{8}StbE).{16}(?!StbE).{4}))', s)
```

Output:

```
['SbbESbbESbbEStbEStbESbbE', 'SbbEStbEStbESbbEStbESttE']
```

Comment: Thank you @Nick. This beautifully solves the specific example I gave, but I was looking for a generic way to match `k` letters/tokens within a substring of length `n` (where `k` and `n` are not fixed; i.e., a pattern that doesn't need to be tailored to each `(k,n)` pair). I imagine that's not possible with regex? Anyway, the `for` loop is a practical workaround.

Comment: @Sia unfortunately the issue with trying to do a generic regex is that you can't stop the lookaheads for `StbE` looking beyond the end of the match, thus giving you false matches e.g. https://regex101.com/r/oPXCED/1. The only way to avoid that would be to iterate over the string in chunks of d*(N+2) characters first, in which case you might as well use my non-regex solution as it will be much faster.