# how to match the re pattern matched earlier in the or pattern

Tags: python, regex, duplicates

i have re pattern

- (?:\S*\s?){0,1}three(?:\S*\s?){0,2}|(?:\S*\s?){0,1}five(?:\S*\s?){0,2}

i have text

- one two three four five six seven eight nine ten

I want the matching result of regex pattern to be as below.

- match1: two three four
- match2: four five six

However, currently, the matching of my patterns is as follows.

- match1: two three four
- match2: five six

How can I solve this problem?

I would like to use or in one regex pattern to match duplicated items without a for statement.

Comment: See [How to use regex to find all overlapping matches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18966891/3832970), that will be the easiest way.

Comment: I would like to use or in one regex pattern to match duplicated items without a for statement.

Comment: Very good, do it as you please.

Comment: Its done like this `(?=((?:\S*\s?){0,1}three(?=((?:\S*\s?){0,2})))|((?:\S*\s?){0,1}five(?=((?:\S*\s?){0,2}))))\1?\3?` where `$0$2$4` is the text match. https://regex101.com/r/peUc0j/1 Did that Duplicate question answer it for you ? No ?

Comment: Above is for Pcre. For Python the replacement is `[\g<0>\2\4] ` https://regex101.com/r/UhpInd/1